# Django validate what user sends from admin panel

Tags: python, django, frameworks, web

I am kind of new to Django, and i am trying to make sort of a news website where users can submit articles(with an account) but the admin needs to check them before they can be posted. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

The simplest approach would be creating simple flag in model let's say a Boolean field named `verified`, which by default would be False. You could add permissions. So in the end you could overwrite a function in your admin form, and show the field for superuser only.

```
class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):

        self.exclude = []
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.exclude.append('Permissions') #here!
        return super(MyUserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```